# Django Ajax calls to load a file not working

Tags: django, jquery

I'm going through Jquery AJAX tutorial in w3schools and trying to simulate a similar call in my Django project.

I want to load a file from the server using Ajax request, I was able to successfully load through load() function by calling a view which is mapped to /ajaxload/ in my urls.py file.

```
$("button").click(function(){
        alert('hi');
        $("p").load("/ajaxload/");
        return false;
    })
```

Can I load the same file by calling .ajax call by passing the url directly?

I apologize if its a very basic question but my new to web development.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"demo_ajax_load.txt",async:false,success:function(result){
      $("div").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button>Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Update:
I read some docs and trying to call view as below but I dont any response

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /* This call is working 
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert('hi');
        $("p").load("/ajaxload/");
        return false;
    })
    */

    //The below call is not working
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert('hi');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajaxload/",
            type: "get",
            data: serializeData,
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response)
            }
        })
        event.preventDefault();

    })

});
```

views.py

```
def ajax_load(request):
    return render(request,'demo_test.txt')
```

urls.py

```
(r'^ajaxload/$',ajax_load),
```

Update:- It started working once the data:serializedata was removed..

Comment: Can we see the view receiving the call?

Comment: @meteorainer: It started worked once the data:serializedata was removed..Not sure why?..Also I have updated with all the details in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`serializeData` is not defined in your js script, so it raises an exception that breaks the run.

Open your browser console, you will see the error.